# PHP support in Glassfish 4

Tags: php, glassfish

I have read in some blog comment that newer versions of glassfish has inbuilt PHP support, is this true?

I am using Glassfish 4 and trying to make wordpress work on it. For this I am trying to use quercus from http://quercus.caucho.com/ but things does seems to work right. I have submitted a question for the same [Exception: WELD-000071 Managed bean class com.caucho.jms.MemoryQueue must be @Dependent while installing Quercus on Glassfish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21162111/exception-weld-000071-managed-bean-class-com-caucho-jms-memoryqueue-must-be-de)

If glassfish 4 has inbuilt PHP support then I do not need to use quercus. If its true, please guide me how to set up a PHP website in glassfish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GlassFish 4 does not have built-in PHP support, nor are there plans to add PHP support in the future.